# Google App Engine ios Endpoint [GTMHTTPFetcher setLoggingEnabled:YES] termination

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, endpoint

for a Google App Engine iOS Endpoint my following commands terminates my code:

[GTMHTTPFetcher setLoggingEnabled:YES]

what is the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

GTMHTTPFetcher is deprecated therefore use [GTMSessionFetcher setLoggingEnabled:YES] instead. also use #import "GTMSessionFetcherLogging.h" to compile